# Why do I get no output when I try to run this Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, panel

When I try to run this code. I get no output. I have the module panel installed but still, nothing is visible when I run this code. Any suggestions?

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

pn.Row('# A', '# B')
```

Comment: Can you attach the code?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. How are you running it? Have you followed the [installation instructions](https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/#jupyterlab-and-classic-notebook)? Edit the question.

Comment: I just ran your code example & this [works](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qrfTYlA_QD2gr9wNrcgepKMEYuecEXj6/view?usp=sharing). Could you give more description? For instance, how did you install `panel`? Do you get any exceptions or something like that?

Comment: I installed panel on jupyter notebook using pip install panel